# Why do different objects with same values cause HashSet.contains to return true?

Tags: java, collections, equals, contains

Below is some code that sees if there is a path in a maze from the top-left to the bottom right.  My question with this code is where we check `failedPoints.contains(p)`: how could we ever get `true`?

Right before we do `if(failedPoints.contains(p))` we are creating a new `Point` object. Even if the new `Point` object has the same `row` and `col` values as another `Point` in `failedPoints`, the objects will be different, so shouldn't `failedPoints.contains(p)` always return `false`?

```
boolean getPath(boolean[][] maze, int row, int col, ArrayList<Point> path, HashSet<Point> failedPoints){
   /*if out of bounds or not available, return*/
   if(col<0 || row<0 || !maze[row][col]){
      return false;
   }
   Point p = new Point(row,col);
   /* If we've already visited this cell return*/
   if(failedPoints.contains(p)){
      return false;
   }

   boolean isAtOrigin = (row == 0) && (col == 0);

   /*If there's a path from start to my current location, add my location.*/
   if(isAtOrigin || getPath(maze,row,col -1, path, failedPoints) || getPath(maze,row-1, col, path,failedPoints)){
      path.add(p);
      return true;
   }
   failedPoints.add(p); //Cache result
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you read what `contains` does? What is unclear?

Comment: .contains will check if the object is contained within the hashset. But if I create a new object that has values the same as another object within the hashset, hashset.contains would still return false if the objects are different even if their properties may be the same

Comment: Thats what is confusing me

Comment: *".contains will check if the object is contained within the hashset."* - Why do you ignore important information? From the JavaDoc: **"if this set contains an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))"**, so it is obviously important how `Point` implemented `equals` (and `hashcode`). Have you read it's source code?

Comment: See also: "[Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the definition of the `Point` class.

Take a look at [the HashSet.contains Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains-java.lang.Object-):

> public boolean contains(Object o)
>
> Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

So if the `Point` class defines an `equals` method that checks to see if its row and column are the same as the row and column of the other point (and also defines a [hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) method that doesn't break the contract), then `failedPoints.contains()` will return true if another `Point` that equals the one being tested is present in the set.

Comment: .equals will check if the two objects are identical not if they share the same property values

Comment: @Matt:  The [`.equals` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) disagree.  It sounds like you are thinking of `==`, which is not used in the general case specifically _because_ it compares object identities instead of object values.